# How to serve an executable

Tags: executable, remote-server, serve

Let's say I have written a simple C program(language doesn't matter), compiled it and now I have the executable.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to serve the program on a webserver so for every connection to the server, the program is executed and the request.body will be treated as stdin and in the response.body the output will be sent back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Program name is: `myprogram` You can use:

```
<?php    
    echo shell_exec("myprogram");
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php    
    echo shell_exec("/bin/bash myprogram");
?>
```

In the above samples `myprogram` should be in current web-folder.

If you have `myprogam` in other foler, then use FULL path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have a web server, that will receive the INPUT from HTML and send it to your backend so that your C program receives it, and executes based on that input, and then you gather that output via your backend, and return it via the web server back to your visitor's screen in some readable or downloadable way.

There are many simple examples where (for example) a Web server (apache2) will take the input fro ma Web page, send it to backend (PHP), php then executes external applicaion to do SOMETHING with the input, and return it via output buffer to PHP, which in turns pushes it back to the Visitor's page in some format:

Checkout: [PHP's ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for documentation and examples